# i'm getting an error in displaying the todo content after deleting one from the list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i'm getting an error in displaying the todo content after deleting one from the list.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/cool-resonance-bxuzk

Comment: when u delete a task, the `task` state becomes an object with `task` as it's key holding the `array` in its value,
add `console.log(task)` before the return and check the logic

Comment: but the "task" hold an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the `setTask` and `filter` method inside the `handleDelete`.

```
const handleDelete = delt => {
  const newTask = task.filter((t, i) => {  // Make changes over here...
    return i !== delt;
  });
  setTask(newTask);  // Make changes over here...
};
const handleClone = index => {
  let clone = task;
  let Arr = clone[index];
  clone.push(Arr);
  setTask(clone);  // Make changes over here...
};
```

Here I have created working code for you
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-waterfall-v7px8

Hope this will work for you.